# Obtain unique entries if condition is met in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Problem:** Suppose I have the below `data.table` object. I want to keep only the entries that satify the following condition:

- For each `CURRENT_DATE` and `IID` only keep the rows with `state = final_e` if there is already a `state = inital_e` on this date for this `IID`.
- For each `CURRENT_DATE` and `IID` if there is `state = e`, this will be unaffected and stay in the data

Any suggestions how to do this such that I obtain the desired object as result? Many thanks!!

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  CURRENT_DATE = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02"),
  IID = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2),
  state = c("init_e", "final_e", "e", "e", "init_e", "final_e"),
  vals = c(10, 20, 30, 22, 9, 7),
  text = c("some_text1", "some_text2", "some_text3", "some_text4", "some_text5", "some_text6")
)

## Output:
   CURRENT_DATE IID   state vals       text
1:   2020-01-01   1  init_e   10 some_text1
2:   2020-01-01   1 final_e   20 some_text2
3:   2020-01-01   2       e   30 some_text3
4:   2020-01-02   1       e   22 some_text4
5:   2020-01-02   2  init_e    9 some_text5
6:   2020-01-02   2 final_e    7 some_text6

## Desired Output:
  CURRENT_DATE IID   state vals       text
1:   2020-01-01   1 final_e   20 some_text2
2:   2020-01-01   2       e   30 some_text3
3:   2020-01-02   1       e   22 some_text4
4:   2020-01-02   2 final_e    7 some_text6
```

**EDIT:**

```
library(data.table)

dt2 <- data.table(
  CURRENT_DATE = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02"),
  IID = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  state = c("init_e", "final_e", "e", "e", "final_e"),
  vals = c(10, 20, 30, 22, 7),
  text = c("some_text1", "some_text2", "some_text3", "some_text4", "some_text5")
)

## Output:
   CURRENT_DATE IID   state vals       text
1:   2020-01-01   1  init_e   10 some_text1
2:   2020-01-01   1 final_e   20 some_text2
3:   2020-01-01   2       e   30 some_text3
4:   2020-01-02   1       e   22 some_text4
5:   2020-01-02   2 final_e    7 some_text5
```

Using this data and one of the answers leads to

```
setorder(dt2[, rn := .I], CURRENT_DATE, IID, state)
dt2[sort(c(dt2[state=="e", which=TRUE],
          unique(dt2[state %chin% c("final_e","init_e")], by=c("CURRENT_DATE","IID"))$rn))]

## Output:
   CURRENT_DATE IID   state vals       text rn
1:   2020-01-01   1  init_e   10 some_text1  1
2:   2020-01-01   2       e   30 some_text3  3
3:   2020-01-02   1       e   22 some_text4  4
4:   2020-01-02   2 final_e    7 some_text5  5

## Desired Output:
   CURRENT_DATE IID   state vals       text
1:   2020-01-01   1 final_e   20 some_text2
3:   2020-01-01   2       e   30 some_text3
4:   2020-01-02   1       e   22 some_text4
5:   2020-01-02   2 final_e    7 some_text5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me also give an answer to my own question as I have found a pretty (obvious) solution:

- essentially, I sort the data.table object first and then take all unique elements (`CURRENT_DATE, IID`) over it
- the "trick" is to encode the `state` variable as ordered factor

```
dt2[, state := factor(state, levels = c("final_e", "init_e", "e"),
                      ordered = TRUE)]

sorted_frame <- dt2[order(CURRENT_DATE, IID, state)]
u_frame <- unique(sorted_frame, by = c("CURRENT_DATE", "IID"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
setkey(dt, CURRENT_DATE, IID, state)[, rn := .I]
dt[sort(c(dt[state=="e", which=TRUE],
    unique(dt[state %chin% c("final_e","init_e")], by=c("CURRENT_DATE","IID"))$rn))]
```

Or simply based on the small sample dataset:

```
dt[state!="init_e"]
```

Comment: many thanks! Sorry, I noticed that my example was not accurate. How do I have to change your code when there is on one date only state `final_e` for a particular `iid` (see edit)?

Comment: on a particular date can be the following combinations of states for a particular IID `(init_e, final_e)`, `(init_e)` or `(final_e)`. If there is the first case `(init_e, final_e)` then always keep `final_e` otherwise (other two cases) leave data as-is. If there appears to be state `e` I want to leave it as well as is in the data. Sorry for being imprecise and many thanks for your help!

Comment: unfortunately not, I used the new data frame `(dt2)` and applied the function. the output is in the edit..

Comment: sorry, corrected `dt2` some_text5 (was a typo). however, i still cannot achieve the desired output (edit)

Comment: @rkraft, sorry for the mistake. I fixed it. the `rn` should be after `setorder`. and i have also used `setkey`

Answer (score 0):

We could write a custom function :

```
check_condition <- function(state) {
     if (any(state == "init_e")) which(state == 'final_e')
     else if(state == 'e') which(state == 'e')
}
```

and apply it for each group.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, .SD[check_condition(state)], .(CURRENT_DATE, IID)]

#   CURRENT_DATE IID   state vals       text
#1:   2020-01-01   1 final_e   20 some_text2
#2:   2020-01-01   2       e   30 some_text3
#3:   2020-01-02   1       e   22 some_text4
#4:   2020-01-02   2 final_e    7 some_text6
```

Comment: hey, thanks! it works, however, it is somehow slow for dataset with 1 mio rows. Do you think there is a more efficient way?

Comment: Definitely, there should be. Can't think of any right now though.